# TypeORM: update entity column with relation (@joinColumn) via Repository

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class UserEntity extends BasicEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    unique: true,
  })
  login: string;
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'wallet' })
export class WalletEntity extends BasicEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: UserEntity;

  @Column({
    name: 'address',
    type: 'text',
  })
  address: string;
}
```

So, the wallet table is looks like this:

```
-------------------------
 id | user_id | address
-------------------------
 1  |    1    |   0x12   
-------------------------
 2  |    43    |  0x10
```

And I like to update the `wallet` entity via Repository api. But the problem is, that I can't just:

```
WalletRepository.save({ address: '0x12', userId: 2 })
```

Because Typescript give me an error, that `userId` should be `userEntity`, but not number. But I want to update a relation column. So is there any option to update it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer, not in TypeORM docs, but [issues Github post](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/238#issuecomment-275360436).

So I need two columns:

```
@Entity({ name: 'wallet' })
export class WalletEntity extends BasicEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (entity: UserEntity) => entity.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: UserEntity;

  @Column({ name: 'user_id', type: 'int' })
  userId: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'address',
    type: 'text',
  })
  address: string;
}
```

with `{name: user_id}` one is for relation, another is for relation update or find value. Which pretty unobvious. So if you want to search for a value by this relation ID, you could do it by the `userID` property of the Entity. But when you are doing `join` part, with `relations[]`, you can access your object by `user` field.

Comment: Thank you for posting your findings, could find very little docs on this

Comment: I think you also need make sure `userId` field can be set to null right? since there will be only one `user_id` field in db, from the many to one relation, a wallet can have user as null, but with the manually defined `userId` field in WalletEntity it insist that user should not be null